# WPF Binding FallbackValue set to Binding

Tags: wpf, data-binding, fallback

Is there a way to have another binding as a fallback value?

I'm trying to do something like this:

```
<Label Content="{Binding SelectedItem.Name, ElementName=groupTreeView,
                         FallbackValue={Binding RootGroup.Name}}" />
```

If anyone's got another trick to pull it off, that would be great.

Answer (score 82, accepted):

What you are looking for is something called PriorityBinding (#6 on [this](http://interactiveasp.net/blogs/natesstuff/archive/2009/01/21/6-things-i-bet-you-didn-t-know-about-data-binding-in-wpf.aspx) list)

(from the article)

> The point to PriorityBinding is to
>   name multiple data bindings in order
>   of most desirable to least desirable.
>   This way if the first binding fails,
>   is empty and/or default, another
>   binding can take it's place.

e.g.

```
<TextBox>
    <TextBox.Text>
        <PriorityBinding>
            <Binding Path="LastNameNonExistant" IsAsync="True" />
            <Binding Path="FirstName" IsAsync="True" />
        </PriorityBinding>
    </TextBox.Text>
</TextBox>
```

Comment: The problem is that PriorityBinding treats a null string as a successful binding

Comment: from the [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.prioritybinding%28v=vs.110%29.aspx): `The value DependencyProperty.UnsetValue is not considered a successful return value.` - so just use a Converter on your binding that returns that property if your value is null. @Shimmy

Answer (score 4):

If you run into problems with binding to null values and PriorityBinding (as Shimmy pointed out) you could go with MultiBinding and a MultiValueConverter like that:

```
public class PriorityMultiValueConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return values.FirstOrDefault(o => o != null);
    }

    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
<TextBox>
    <TextBox.Text>
        <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource PriorityMultiValueConverter}">
            <Binding Path="LastNameNull" />
            <Binding Path="FirstName" />
        </MultiBinding>
    </TextBox.Text>
</TextBox>
```

Answer (score 3):

Under what conditions would you like it to use the Fallback value? How would you determine that a binding has failed?  A binding is still valid even if it's bound to a null value.

I think a good bet may be to use a converter to convert to a default value if the binding returns null.  I'm not sure how you could default to another bound value though.

Check out [converters here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752347.aspx#data_conversion)

Comment: In my case, it's where I'm 90%+ sure that the `DataContext` will have a specific property on it, but I want to fall back to calling `.ToString()` where/if it doesn't.