# wpf: changing the value of a Dependency Property from viewmodel

Tags: wpf, dependency-properties

I have a custom usercontrol with a custom dependency property of type string. It should be bound twoway to a textbox, which is in a surrounding app, like this:

```
<Textbox Name="TextBoxInHostApp"/>
<ctrl:MyControl 
     ....
         MyString = "{Binding ElementName=TextBoxInHostApp, Path=Text, Mode=TwoWay}"
</ctrl:MyControl>
```

Problem:

The Control should have the functionality to reveal the value of the dependency property also!

In MyControl, I have a simple string property "Name", which should update the MyString dependeny property value.

So normally, if MyString was not bound to the outside world, you would code in the xaml where the control is used:

```
<Textbox Name="TextBoxInHostApp"/>
<ctrl:MyControl 
     ....
         MyString = "{Binding Name}"
</ctrl:MyControl>
```

But that's not available in my case.

Attempt 1:
I used a trigger inside the usercontrol xaml:

```
<UserControl.Style>
    <Style>
        <Style.Setters>
            <Setter Property="local:MyControl.MyString" Value="{Binding Name, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
        </Style.Setters>
    </Style>
```

Now this trigger doesn't work, because the "local value" of the dp is already set here:

```
MyString = "{Binding ...
```

if i comment out:

```
<!--<MyString = "{Binding ...
```

...the trigger works fine, because the "local value" isn't set.

next attempt:
I try the hard way and code in MyControls viewmodel:

```
public string Name
{
    get
    {
        return _name;
    }
    set
    {
        _name = value;
         RaisePropertyChanged("Name");

         MyOwningUICtrl.SetValue(MyControl.MyStringProperty, value); // ??
    }
}
```

I have to pass a DependencyObject to call a SetValue, which is unpleasant for MVVM. There must be better solutions for this scenario ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is by design

Per WPF's [Dependency Property Precedence List](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743230.aspx#listing), values specified locally within a `<Tag>` will always take precedence over values specified in a `Style` or a `Trigger`

A common problem is setting a value in a `<Tag>`, then trying to change it in a `Style.Trigger`. The solution is to set the default value as a `<Setter>` in the `<Style>` instead of in the `<Tag>`, which will then allow the triggered value to take precedence over the styled value

```
<Style>
    <!-- Default Value
    <Setter Property="local:MyControl.MyString" 
            Value="{Binding ElementName=TextBoxInHostApp, Path=Text, Mode=TwoWay}"/>

    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger ...>
            <!-- Triggered Value -->
            <Setter Property="local:MyControl.MyString" 
                    Value="{Binding Name, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Setters>
</Style>
```

But I don't actually see a Trigger defined in your post anywhere, so I'm not really sure if this is your problem or not.

I'm a bit unclear about the exact structure of your code, but keep in mind that a Dependency Property is kind of like a pointer to another value. You can set it to point to `TextBox.Text`, or to point to `DataContext.Name`, but not both.

If you want to set both `TextBox.Text` and `MyUserControl.MyString` to point to `DataContext.Name`, then you should bind both properties to `"{Binding Name}"` like [Natxo suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15617291/302677).

Or if you are trying to bind `MyString` to `UserControl.Name` if `MyString` is not specified in the `<ctrl:MyControl ...>` tag, then you can try using a [PriorityBinding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.prioritybinding.aspx) (example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1916488/302677)), or just expose the `Name` property to the outside world to let outside elements use the control like `<ctrl:MyControl Name="{Binding ...}" />`

Comment: 1st) Your right, i use a style setter, not a trigger. 2nd) The textbox.text should be the property that is bound to the MyString dp. The design fact is, that the value of the dp can change in two ways: from a textbox on the app layout, and from a textbox inside the custom control.

Comment: the non-smart solution i just tested: MyOwningUICtrl.SetValue(MyControl.MyStringProperty, value); // ??     ...works fine, but it's not good programming i think

Comment: @deafjeff Keep in mind that bindings are like pointers - they point to a value in the `DataContext` somewhere. It sounds like you want your `MyString` dependency property to point to some value outside the `UserControl` (such as `{Binding Name}`, and you want `TextBox.Text` to point to `UserControl.MyString`. So your end result is `<TextBox Text={Binding ElementName=MyUserControl, Path=MyString}" />` and `<ctrl:MyUserControl MyString="{Binding Name}" />`

Comment: Now that is plausible! Thank You!!

Answer (score 1):

If you display in both the Textbox and Mycontrol the same value... why dont you bind them to that property? :

```
<Textbox Name="TextBoxInHostApp" Text="{Binding Name}"/>
<ctrl:MyControl 
     ....
         MyString="{Binding Name}"
</ctrl:MyControl>
```

Comment: The point is the app has no access to the "Name" property. The app string represented by the textbox should modify the usercontrols "via the "MyString" dp. That "Name" is set inside the "MyString"- ChangedCallback is not relevant here.The thing is that "Name" is allowed to modify the "MyString" dp, and so, if "Name" from inside the control changes, the text in the apps textbox also should change.